# transform: translate feature makes the logo blurred

Tags: html, css

my web site retrokent.com
My problem is the logo is blurry. transform: translate and webkit-transform: translate

```
.nm-header.centered .nm-header-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

The problem is solved when I turn off the "transform: translate" and "webkit-transform: translate" features.

But then the logo is position shifting. How can I fix it? Can you help me?

screenshot-1 : https://prnt.sc/tr16j4
screenshot-2 : https://prnt.sc/tr16te

Comment: Try exporting your logo in svg or any vector format, or at a higher resolution.
EDIT: This would not really solve the issue, it is more of a workaround, but it should work. Additionnally, vector graphics (svg) are cool, because they take up much less space than traditionnal raster graphics (png,jpeg etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You can center your image without `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` just change in your css.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
```

for responsive you can set `text-align: center` with `media queries`.